# InstallShield - Error 429 and missing sabuild.dll

Tags: installshield

We've recently upgraded from InstallShield 2015 to 2016 SP2.  I opened my existing Projects in 2016, and InstallShield upgraded them with no errors.  But when I try to build in the GUI I get the following:

> Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object

When I try to build using the commandline...

```
IsCmdBld.exe -p "C:\Path to IS Project file\ProjectFile.ism" -v
```

...I get the following:

> InstallShield (R) Release Builder Copyright (c) 2016 Flexera Software
>   LLC.
>
> All Rights Reserved.
>   -1131: Failed to load sabuild.dll.

We have several older versions of InstallShield on the particular machine.  These Project files were working fine until I tried building them in 2016.  I can open copies of the backed up Project files in 2015 and they still build without error.  I have searched the entire computer for "sabuild.dll".  None found.

This occurs when I try to build MSI or EXE.

We have InstallShield 2016 SP2 Professional and the update manager says we are on the latest.  This is installed on Windows 10 Pro 32-bit (don't ask, I'm not operations and I inherited this setup).

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually InstallShield only supports running as a 32bit process so you are good to go on that. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package.

Also Installshield 2016 originally had an issue with detecting vc++ libraries, so you may need to update to SP2.

Refer IOJ-1742525 on http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/ReleaseNotes.htm

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly the solution, but definitely pointed me in the right direction.

I installed C++ 2013 Redistributable.  I also installed C++ 2015 Redistributable (per the prerequisites listed in your link).  That didn't do the trick alone.  I also went back to the install files that one of our ops guys downloaded.  There was a "InstallShieldPrereqs.exe" that no one seemed to remember installing.  So I installed that, re-ran the IS 2016 SP2 installer (did a repair), and all is working normally.